# How to calculate sum of the difference between two dates

Tags: django

I have this model

```
class Exemple(models.Model):
 from_date = models.DateField()
 until_date = models.DateField()
 person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have a number per year, exemple 100 and I must to decrease that number from the sum of days of that person. I must to calculate day on every row of that person and then to make sum  and then 100 - sum of days

Comment: What is the number of days here. Imagine that `from_date` is `9-12-2019 00:00:00` and `until_date` is `9-12-2019 12:34:56`? Do we count that as a full day? Or `0.51` day?

Comment: Could you try to reformulate your question ? Or to give an example ? I have to admit I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Ibris: I think he wants something like `100 - Sum(until_date-from_date)`, but the details are not entirely clear as to when we are talking about a "full" day.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem will be one day.  I did a mistake the field is models.DateField() not datetime

Comment: @lbris i want to calculate the sum of days for every person in the current year

Comment: @Florin: if both days are the same, does that count as *zero* days, or *one* day?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 1 day

Comment: @Florin: what database backend do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203924/discussion-between-florin-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @Florin I added an answer with a little sample of code that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering `persons` contains your persons, you could do something like that :

```
for person in persons:
  sum = 0
  for exemple in Exemple.objects.filter(person=person):
    sum += max(1, exemple.until_date - exemple.from_date)
```

Explanation :

1) You do the computation person per person

2) For each person, you browse every `exemple`

3) You sum every "until - from". The `max()` is here to return `1` if `until_date = from_date` is equal to `0` (because you said you don't want it to be `0`)

I don't know if you want to store it somewhere or if you just want to do it in a method so I just wrote this little sample of code to provide you the logic. You'll have to adapt it to suit your needs.

However this might not be the prettier way to achieve your goal.